# CSS-Animation go to the right

Tags: css, animation

I have a problem with CSS currently.

https://jsfiddle.net/k9cfdofv/1/

There you can see that the 
stripe (parallelogram) comes from the bottom, but it goes a little bit to right before it goes in that state I want it.
So I want it come from the bottom and go to the top without this shift at the end.

CSS-Code:

```
   .stripe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background: red;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    animation: ani 1s linear 1 forwards;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}



@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 700px;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/k9cfdofv/7/

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by setting a transform-origin for element to be skewed to left bottom.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  animation: ani 1s linear 10 forwards;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```